# Getting Encrypted message due to my own application in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
public void readSMS() {
        System.out.println("Inside of SMS Reading.......");
        Uri SMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body", "date" };
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Inside of SMS Reading Try.......");
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMSURI, projection, null // selection
                    , null // selectionArgs
                    , null); // sortOrder

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    // System.out.println("Inside of SMS Reading DO.......");
                    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    String address = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("address"));
                    String body = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("body"));
                    String date = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("date"));

                    SMSNo.add(address);
                    SMSText.add(body);
                    SMSType.add("Incoming");
                    SMSTime.add(getSMSTime(Long.parseLong(date)));

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                // readOutgoingSMS();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error = " + e.toString());

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am developing an app in which user can upload their messages to server and can download them whenever they want. But i am getting a very strange error.Whenever i receive a message in my default messages it shows me 2 messages,one is encrypted.and it also shows me a toast that my application has stopped working. Can anyone tell me why it is happening?

Comment: and the code. just give us something to look at.

Comment: I can not post log just because it is happening when the application is installed in my phone and if someone sends me a message on my phone.

Comment: This is the method which i am using to fetch messages from device.